# Can I use PCIe SSD card in my motherboard?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, pci-express, m.2

My motherboard Name: GA-H61M-S2PV (rev. 2.2)
Detail link: https://www.gigabyte.com/bd/Motherboard/GA-H61M-S2PV-rev-22/sp#sp

Expansion Slots:
    **1 x PCI Express x16 slot, running at x16
    (The PCI Express x16 slot conforms to PCI Express 3.0 standard.)
    * Whether PCI Express 3.0 is supported depends on CPU and graphics card compatibility.**
    1 x PCI Express x1 slot
    (The PCI Express x1 slot conforms to PCI Express 2.0 standard.)
    2 x PCI slots

Answer (score 1):

Not as is. It has no M.2 slot.

If the PCIe (PCIe = PCI Express) x16 slot is not in use, you could add a [PCIe M.2 SATA controller card](https://www.newegg.com/p/14U-00GH-00014?item=9SIAHEA7S34158) ([another](https://www.cdw.com/product/ASUS-HYPER-M.2-X16-CARD-V2-interface-adapter-M.2-Card-PCIe-3.0-x16/5549599)) ([another](https://www.newegg.com/p/35Y-005D-00011?item=9SIABP58NA8823)).

However, I have never found a PCI 2.0 M.2 adapter card, nor have I found an M.2 adapter for a PCIe x1 slot, and I've done a lot of looking recently.

Please, someone prove me wrong.